# What is the preferred way communicating with JVMTI agent?

Tags: java, jvm, jvmti

I'm writing some simple monitoring tool to take some general metrics from a running JVM using JVMTI. I'm intended to send this metrics data to Zabbix or Graphite in order to analyze later.

What is the preferred way to communicate with agent? The only way I can think of is reinventing a wheel and implement some socket based communication protocol.

Comment: The preferred way depends on the actual task you have to solve. When you only look at the underlying mechanism (like “socket”), everything will look like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Holger The example is to subscribe to the "exceptions" event and aggregate metrics from all exceptions thrown (caught/uncaught).